# What does the regression model look like if the predictors are categorical?

Tags: r, regression, lm

I was reading ["The lm() function with categorical predictors"](http://anythingbutrbitrary.blogspot.com/2012/04/lm-function-with-categorical-predictors.html), and am confused.

1. What does the regression model with a categorical predictor look
   like, with the following R code:

   ```
   n = 30
   sigma = 2.0

   AOV.df <- data.frame(category = c(rep("category1", n)
                                   , rep("category2", n)
                                   , rep("category3", n)), 
                               j = c(1:n
                                   , 1:n
                                   , 1:n),
                               y = c(8.0  + sigma*rnorm(n)
                                   , 9.5  + sigma*rnorm(n)
                                   , 11.0 + sigma*rnorm(n))
                     )

   AOV.lm <- lm(y ~ category, data = AOV.df)
   summary(AOV.lm)
   ```

   The output is:

   ```
   Coefficients:
                     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
   (Intercept)         8.4514     0.3405  24.823  &lt; 2e-16 ***
   categorycategory2   0.8343     0.4815   1.733   0.0867 .  
   categorycategory3   3.0017     0.4815   6.234 1.58e-08 ***
   ---
   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

   Residual standard error: 1.865 on 87 degrees of freedom
   Multiple R-squared: 0.3225, Adjusted R-squared: 0.307 
   F-statistic: 20.71 on 2 and 87 DF,  p-value: 4.403e-08
   ```

   Is the model:

   *y = 8.4514 + 0.8343 for category 1*,

   *y = 8.4514 + 0.8343 for category 2* or

   *y = 8.4514 + 3.0017 for cateogry 3*?
2. What is the model if the R code looks like:

   ```
   > X <- read.table("http://www.stat.umn.edu/geyer/5102/data/ex5-4.txt", header=T) 
   > lm(y ~ color + x * color, data=X)

   Call:
   lm(formula = y ~ color + x * color, data = X)

   Coefficients:
    (Intercept)    colorgreen      colorred             x  colorgreen:x  
       13.96118       0.25243       6.10543       0.97241       0.07347  
     colorred:x  
        0.01962
   ```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

1. Your model is this:

   y = 8.4514 + (0.8343 * category2) + (3.0017 * category3)

   where `category2` is an indicator (0/1 "dummy" variable) that is 1 when `category==2` and 0 otherwise and where `category3` is an indicator (0/1 "dummy" variable) that is 1 when `category==3` and 0 otherwise. The baseline level of the `category` variable is dropped due to multicollinearity.
2. You'll see something similar if you include an interaction term, with one level of the categorical variable excluded and interaction terms between `x` and the remaining category levels. The coefficient on `x` will represent the marginal effect of `x` when `category==1` and the interaction terms will be the marginal effects of `x` when `category==2` and `category==3`, respectively. The indicators `categorycategory2` and `categorycategory3` will take on a slightly different meaning, as well, being the marginal effects of the `category2` and `category3` indicators when `x==0`.

Also, as a side note:
Since you have a model with all indicator variables, you may also find the no-intercept model intuitive (since it looks like you're working from an ANOVA mindset), in which case the coefficients are group means:

```
> summary(lm(y ~ 0 + category, data = AOV.df))

                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
categorycategory1   8.1714     0.3247   25.16   <2e-16 ***
categorycategory2   9.4185     0.3247   29.00   <2e-16 ***
categorycategory3  10.8858     0.3247   33.52   <2e-16 ***
```

Comment: Thanks. how about part 2 in my post?

Comment: Thanks, Thomas! I am still not very clear about part 2. I just added an example. It will clarify my confusion, if you could write out the model in part 2.

Answer (score 1):

```
lm(y ~ color + x * color, data = X)
```

is redundant because "x * color" is interpreted as "x + color + x:color" where "x:color" is the interaction between x and color.

```
lm(y ~ x * color, data = X)
```

is enough. The model is:
$$y = \beta_0+\beta_1 x+\beta_2 color + \beta_3 x\,color + \varepsilon$$
Because color is a three-level factor, you can read it as:
$$y=\beta_0+\beta_1 x+\beta_{2g}(color = green)+\beta_{2r}(color=red)+\beta_{3g}x(color=green)+\beta_{3r}x(color=red)+\varepsilon$$
i.e.:

- when color is "blue": $y=13.96+0.97x$;
- when color is "green": $y=13.96+0.97x+0.25+0.07x=(13.96+0.25)+(0.97+0.07)x$;
- when color is "red": $y=13.96+0.97x+6.11+0.02x=(13.96+6.11)+(0.97+0.02)x$.